# What are the differences between require 'capybara/rails' and 'capybara/rspec' in rails spec/spec_helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

With capybara2.0, what are the differences, and which is better in my new app?

My understanding, `require 'capybara/rails'` is better, and use below:

```
spec/{controllers,models,...} #=> rspec
spec/requests #=> rspec
spec/features #=> capybara
```

`capybara/rspec` is capybara1, old and `spec/requests #=> rspec, capybara`, this is not simple.

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rails.rb
https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/rspec.rb